# Question on using Monitor.TryEnter and locking object

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

Consider the following function that implements non-blocking access to only the one thread.

```
public bool TryCancelGroup()
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(_locked))
    {
        if (_locked == false)
        {
            _locked = true;

            try
            {
                // do something
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _locked = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_locked);
            }
        }
        return _locked;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is how `_locked` variable is defined.

```
bool _locked = false;
```

Now when program reaches `Monitor.Exit(_locked);` it throws an `System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException` saying that _locked variable was not synchronized before.

It all was working before when _locked variable was defined as object

```
object _locked = new object();
```

When I changed it to bool in order to use it as boolean flag I started getting this exception.

Comment: JaredPar has provided the answer for your problem. But your logic seems to be flawed - if you enter into monitor with _locked = true then you will never exit the monitor.

Comment: Oh certainly yes, thanks VinayC

Comment: Also I think you usually have a static object as your lock.

Comment: @Chris. Not in my case. I need provided synchronization for class instance not for class type. Thus I don't need static lock object.

Comment: Cool. I did think that might be the case but wanted to check it wasn't just a typo or something. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The reason why is that the `Monitor` methods all take a `System.Object` parameter.  When you pass in a `bool` a box is required to convert to `Object`.  The box operation produces a new `System.Object` value for each call.  So the `TryEnter` and `Exit` methods see different objects and results in the exception.

When `_locked` was typed to `Object` there was no need for a box.  Hence the `TryEnter` and `Exit` methods see the same object and can function correctly.

A few other comments about the code

- TryEnter must be paired with Exit in all cases and for sanity sake the Exit call should be in a finally block.  Otherwise you're inviting a deadlock scenario
- The `_locked` variable is only set to `false` in the face of an exception.  If execution does not produce an exception it will remain true and no thread will ever again enter the `if` block.

Comment: O yeah boxing sure. But isn't bool type derived from System.Object? So it is derived from Object, but nevertheless when a conversion to Object is met somewhere a boxing operation is used? Is this statement correct?

Comment: @Captain, when a value type of any kind, `bool` included, is used in a location typed to `System.Object` or an interface a boxing operation will occur.

Answer (score 8):

Setting the timeout on a monitor to 0 can help implement the behaviour you want. Use a globally declared object to lock against.

```
static object mylock = new object();
```

....

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(mylock, 0))
{
    try
    {
           // Do work
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(mylock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Monitor.TryEnter(mylock, 0) is the same as Monitor.TryEnter(mylock) as far as I can see in reflector.

Comment: Not from my experience. I added the ", 0" to mine and it fixed the problem I was having.

Comment: @Andrew `static object var mylock` is not valid variable declaration.

Comment: @DerreckDean - surprising that adding `, 0` fixed a bug; the [monitor spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h9d380(v=vs.110).aspx) says 0 is same as omitting the parameter: "*If millisecondsTimeout equals 0, this method is equivalent to TryEnter(Object).*"

Comment: @tchelidze - I agree, so I've edited to fix the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the success above - to be sure the lock is released - the TryEnter() and Exit() can be wrapped in a custom class as an extension to *object* taking a Delegate and Timeout as a parameter.

```
public static class MyMonitor
{

    public static bool TryEnter(this object obj, Action action, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(obj, millisecondsTimeout))
            {
                try
                {
                    action();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(obj);
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

And called like this waiting 1000 ms to obtain the lock or throw an error if timeout:

```
if (!_locked.TryEnter(() =>
{
    //Exclusive access code placed here..
}, 1000)) {
    throw new TimeoutException("Timeout waiting for exclusive access");
}
```

This way the forgetting the *Monitor.Exit()* is not an option.